Alternative For Type.IsSerializable
We used in an application
if (!value!.GetType().IsSerializable)
    return;

In the meantime the IsSerializable property is obsolete (Formatter-based serialization is obsolete and should not be used.).
What is the new way to do that in .Net 8?

Please refer https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/34893
Main recommendation is to get away with binary serialization due to security issues.
Less common pattern (not recommended as well) is to relay on Serializable attribute.

I assume you are going to serialize the object using BinaryFormatter if IsSerlaizable is true? You should not do that anymore. Pick another way of serialization. The answer to the question of "how to check if a type is serializable" depends on what serialization method you picked.

@pwas "get away with binary serialization" - suggesting that binary serialization is unsafe whereas text-base serialization is safe is misleading. The problem is not with the binary format (eg. ProtoBuf is safe, though it's also binary) but with polymorphism (which can make a text-based serializer also unsafe, eg. Newtonsoft's JSON.NET if we allow resolving type names). See a more elaborated explanation in this answer of mine to a somewhat related question.

The most viable alternative is using the Data Contract. It is also easy to use, a totally transparent and type-agnostic technology with good performance (due to assemblies generated on the fly using System.Reflection.Emit under the hood. Everything is explained in the documentation.
